# Connect to Chevrolet Cruze Hot-Spot Wi-Fi

Tags: security, wifi, smart-cars

The Chevrolet Cruze (2016) is supposed to have a Wi-Fi hot-spot.  I do see it showing up in my available network connections, but how do I find the password?  From my memory, the dealer didn't say what it was, and if they did, I don't remember what it was.

**Is there a way to find my Chevrolet Cruze's Wi-Fi hotspot password on the car?**  (Obviously, I have physical access.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to OnStar - [Connecting to your vehicle's Wi-Fi Hotspot](https://www.onstar.com/us/en/services/connections/4glte/setup_support.html)

> To get your hotspot name (SSID) and password, press the Voice Command button and say "Wi-Fi settings."